# Trouble with htmlunit

Tags: java, gwt

i have a gwt url and i am trying to get next page by clicking a button.
That button is an image.
But when we click that button i got blank page.
That url is:

```
http://www.ichotelsgroup.com/redirect?brandCode=hi&regionCode=1&localeCode=en&path=asearch&errorURL=/h/d/6c/1/en/rates&successURL=/h/d/6c/1/en/rates/BOSGC&availabilitySearchSuccessURL=/h/d/6c/1/en/rates/BOSGC?ias=y&actionName=availabilitySearch&hotelCode=BOSGC&checkInDate=2&checkInMonthYear=62010&checkOutDate=6&checkOutMonthYear=62010&numberOfAdults=1&numberOfChildren=0&numberOfRooms=1&smokingPreference=3&secure=false&rateTypeCodes=6CBARC&rateChangePeriod=&_IATAno=99609020&cm_mmc=mdpr-_-kayak-_-USCSR-_-BOSGC
```

i am trying to click "view rates button"..

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to investigate, please provide locally deployable application with '-style PRETTY', or try to isolate the root cause as hinted in [here](http://htmlunit.svn.sf.net/viewvc/htmlunit/trunk/htmlunit/src/site/xdoc/submittingJSBugs.xml?view=markup).